# ActionScript Preloader More Detailed Percentages

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, preloader

I am building a preloader for a flash application I am building. I am looking for a way to gain more detailed percentages from the `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` that all preloaders use to track downloading progress. When I run a `trace()` statement on the loader percentages for a small file, my output window displays something like this:

```
4
8
13
17
23 etc...
```

I am looking for a way to be able to monitor this progress more closely, so I get `1, 2, 3, etc...`. If numbers are repeated, that is okay. Parts of my preloader rely on these values, and thus, it would be great to be able to get them from 1 - 100 with no skipped whole numbers.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you using some kind of packaged preloader or doing it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make sense - unless your internet connection loaded **exactly 1%** of the file at a time.

What's happening is that after each new packet is received, it could be any size based on your download speed (let's say between 200 and 230kb). `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` is dispatched each time one of these is received, adding to the total percentage loaded as you would expect.

So basically, let's say we're loading a **1000kb** file, and your download speed is **100-150kbps**.

Each `trace()` in your function called on each dispatch of `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` will be run when a new packet has been received, so:

> 100kb loaded - 100 total - traces
>   10
>  120kb loaded - 220 total -
>   traces 22
>  150kb loaded - 370
>   total - traces 37

Etc.

Comment: Ah... good details. Looks like I will have to compensate with some additional ActionScript for this kind of detail. Thanks for you help, Marty!

Comment: I could, but it is rather a unique preloader (not one of the traditional progress-bar ones), and it is inside of a BIG class that's just gettin' bigger! I know how to compensate for these gaps in ActionScript, so I think I will just do that. I was just looking for a quick work-around. Thanks for your willingness to help, though!

Comment: @spryno724 No worries, though having a 'large' pre-loader could be an issue in itself.

Comment: Just want to make a point that by not posting the code we'll never be 100% sure of what exactly the issue was. I've upvoted the answer though because Marty has explained the functionality well so you should at least now be able to understand how to change up your code to suit your needs. It just FEELS like an unanswered question still because of the inability to specifically identify the issue.

Comment: Though I agree with this, it's pretty easy for me to work out what the problem is based on the fact that he's loading **something** and tracking the progress of the load via ProgressEvent.PROGRESS. There aren't a lot of way this could be coded differently.

Comment: @Marty I didn't mean that the actual size of the SWF that is large, just the ActionScript is too large to paste on a discussion forum. :D

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you need these percentages for? There's no ways to force URLLoader to give you something like an update on every 1% but you can fake it.

If you want to estimate your download speed you can get the time with getTimer and the amount downloaded so far from the ProgressEvent every time you get a progress event; once you have that you can compare the new vs. old values and get an approximation of your download speed.

You can do a similar thing smooth out a progress bar, once you have a download rate you can tweet your progress bar and get a small update every frame and a more accurate update every time you get a ProgressEvent.

Answer (score -2):

How fast is your framerate? It could be that it's set too low, causing the progress to refresh less often. I'd try increasing your framerate or the main movie.

Another common way is to simulate it by tweening values between the two intervals, so it looks smoother. But it doesn't quite sound like what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hmm... I'll take a look at that. The only issue may be is the fact that is is located in a external class.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like increasing the frame-rate, say to 100, didn't work.

Comment: The display list has absolutely nothing to do with the ProgressEvent, unless he is doing is tracing inside an ENTER_FRAME, which wouldn't be the case given that he is using ProgressEvent in the first place.